# C++ inheritance of linked list

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, linked-list, virtual-inheritance

```
class LinkedList{
    public:
    int data;
    LinkedList *next;
};

class NewLinkedList: public LinkedList{
    public:
    int data2;
};
```

When I use `NewLinkedList`, its `next` is still a pointer to `LinkedList` instead of `NewLinkedList`, so that I cannot access `newlinkedlist.next->data2` without type casts. (`newlinkedlist` is an object of `NewLinkedList`.)

How can I design these two classes to avoid this problem?

Is there something like `SELF_TYPE *next;` and it becomes the type of derived class itself automatically when it is inherited?

Comment: How is your question about virtual inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
public:
    int data;
    T * next;
};

class NewLinkedList: public LinkedList<NewLinkedList>{
public:
    int data2;
};
```

This technique is known as the **Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)**

To improve the design, your `LinkedList` class should not contain any data other than what is needed for the linked list mechanism : it should be a  base class only. Then you subclass it as above with specialized classes.

Comment: Then how can I use the `LinkedList` base class?

Comment: I think not having to use LinkedList directly, only through subclasses, would be a better design. LinkedList would not store any data (remove the data member) and would be a pure linked list template.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, make the parent class as abstract and make the data members private(in most of the cases, that should be done; unless you have some really good reason not to do so) and add abstract functions to access these members. That would be a good design and would solve your problem as well.

Comment: I have to use type casts in the implementation of the abstract function in derived class. e.g. `return (Derived*)Base::get_next();`

Answer (score -1):

Lets suppose what you wish to achieve is possible.

Consider:

```
class AveryNewLinkedList: public LinkedList{
    public:
    int data2;
};
```

Will `next` be of a type `AveryNewLinkedList` or `NewLinkedList`?

The compiler does not know - nor do you.

So inheritance means you get bits from your parents and add to them - but the parents do not get anything from you!